# Scripting error in jQuery/AJAX code snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

this should be a simple question, but the answer has eluded me for some time now. I seem to have an error in this code, either a scripting typo, or an error in my logic. Could you kindly clarify my problem?

Here's the code:

```
function GetQuestion() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "questions.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                x = 0;
                x = $(xml).find('Question').length;

                var questionID = $.random(x);

                $(xml).find('Question').each(function(){
                    if(this.ID == questionID) {
                        var text = $(this).find('BODY').text();
                        $('#questionBody')[0].innerHTML = text;
                    }
                }); //close each
            } //close success
        });//close ajax
    }; //close function GetQuestion
```

It's meant to read in an XML file, search it for a specific item with a random ID, and plug the contents of `BODY` into a `<p>` I have in my HTML file. However, it isn't working as expected. Where have I made an error?

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville

Comment: Do you *get* any error? What is `$.random()` ?

Comment: It's a custom function I downloaded. Do you want to see it? No, I don't get a single error, not even from Firebug.

Comment: what is the problem. You say that you seem to have an error but there is not error. So what's not working as expected?

Comment: How do you invoke GetQuestion()?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  If FireBug isn't working for you, the put alerts everywhere in your success function.  

Do you see any call/response in Firebug? How are you calling the function?

Comment: Try debugging out the 'this.ID' in the find... not sure if jquery will do that properly on xml -- might try .attr('ID'). If that is koshier, try looking your 'text' to make sure it is finding the BODY properly. Lastly if text is coming in okay, to insert the text instead of innerhtml, try $(elem).html(text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a general observation and not really an answer, but it may help you in the future:

```
//notice that this function is much easier to consume in one glance
function GetQuestion() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "questions.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: GetQuestionSuccess
    });//close ajax

}; //close function GetQuestion  // <-superfluous semicolon?



//notice that this function is much easier to consume in one glance
function GetQuestionSuccess(xml) {

    //let's quit querying each time we need them
    var questions = $(xml).find('Question');  //bonus, it's a jQuery object!

    //x = 0; // <-unnecessary assignment. It gets obliterated on the next line.
    x = questions.length; //the count of all "Question"s found

    var questionID = $.random(x);

    //but wait, read my next comments below
    questions.each(function(){
        if(this.ID == questionID) {
            var text = $(this).find('BODY').text();
            $('#questionBody')[0].innerHTML = text;
        }
    }); //close each

    //since you seem to be looking for the index questionID of all the questions, 
    //why not jump to that one instead of looping?
    //also, if you only have one "#questionbody" in your document you can do this more "jquery"ish.
    $('#questionBody')[0].innerHTML = questions[questionID].find('BODY').text();

    //only one:
    $('#questionBody').html( questions[questionID].find('BODY').text() );

} //close success
```

so to clarify :\

```
//I shredded it down to a reasonable number of lines. Could be shorter still, albeit less readable.
//but I think this is pretty readable.
function GetQuestionSuccess(xml) {

    var questions = $(xml).find('Question');

    var questionID = $.random(questions.length);

    $('#questionBody').html( questions[questionID].find('BODY').text() );

} //close success
```

Comment: Thanks for that observation. It seems like you put a lot more effort into this answer, so I'm accepting it rather than the other one, since neither actually address the problem, which actually, to my dismay, lay elsewhere. Thank you for the time you put into this.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville ~ well thanks, I suppose. I really didn't put _that_ much time into it, about three times what it took to type it out, which at 60wpm wasn't that long ... I just thought you might like to see a simpler refactoring of the code that should've sped things up a slight notch (losing the foreach does that). So you found the problem elsewhere? Care to share what was actually causing you grief?

Comment: I suppose. But first, think on this: Every programmer has at least one total "Do'h!!" moment in his/her life. This was mine; I didn't have the XML file in the right directory at all. My code probably worked fine after all. Yours works better, though. I will probably implement it.

Comment: I'm sure your code _did_ work fine. I'm glad you found your error. And if you think you're only going to have one "d'oh!" moment then ... I wish you luck. I have those two or three times a month, at a minimum. Local maximums approach one an hour, but that usually also includes beer ;) ... So long as my rewrite makes sense and you understand what it does, then feel free to use it. I would encourage you to try benchmarking the two of them (jsperf comes to mind) and see which approach works better and why. They may be nearly similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your xml looks something like this (since you didn't post it) (note case sensitivty in tags)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<questionlist>
<Question ID='0'>
<BODY>
Are you 1?
</BODY>
</Question>
<Question ID='1'>
<BODY>
Are you 2?
</BODY>
</Question>
<Question ID='2'>
<BODY>
Are you 3?
</BODY>
</Question>
<Question ID='3'>
<BODY>
Are you 4?
</BODY>
</Question>
<Question ID='4'>
<BODY>
Are you 5?
</BODY>
</Question>
<Question ID='5'>
<BODY>
Are you 6?
</BODY>
</Question>
<Question ID='6'>
<BODY>
Are you 7?
</BODY>
</Question>
</questionlist>
```

Then you can use this modified version of your code...

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">


function GetQuestion() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "questions.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                x = 0;
                x = $(xml).find('Question').length;
                var questionID = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);

                $(xml).find('Question').each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('ID') == questionID) {
                        var text = $(this).find('BODY').text();
                        $('#questionBody').html(text);
                    }
                }); //close each
            } //close success
        });//close ajax
    }; //close function GetQuestion

        $(document).ready(function(){
        GetQuestion();
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="questionBody"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed the $.random method, I didn't appear to have this method so I used regular JS, I changed this.ID to use the jquery selector to check the id attribute, and I changed your innerHTML line to use the jquery html() function.  The only problem with the code is the fact that you are relying on the fact you will have questions with id's of n-1 entries...